# Using WebGL in native Android App

Tags: android, ios, webgl

I need to make a 3D animation across the web, android and iOS platforms. My question is, is it possible to use WebGL to make the animations in native android and iOS apps? As I would write the animation once and it would in theory port to the android and iOS with out any problems or am I going to have to simply use the OpenGL ES to make the animations for the mobile devices and webGL for the web.

Comment: i can only tell you about Android's WebView ... WebGL is not supported here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work for ludei

So, that's exactly what [a company called ludei is preparing to launch](http://thenextweb.com/insider/2013/03/25/ludei-to-add-webgl-3d-support-this-summer-as-it-opens-up-its-html5-game-platform-to-more-titles/) ;)

We have it working on Android 2.3 (even on a Nexus One!) through 4.2, and iOS 4 (I think?) and up. We don't rely on the system browsers or webviews, so there are no "private libraries" problems, and we support versions of Android that can't have WebGL otherwise.

We're giving it the final touches now, but we should be able to release it in a few weeks :)

Answer (score 0):

WebGL is not fully supported on all browsers, however both Android and iOS have native OpenGL views that can be used (and will provide a much faster experience than WebGL). Once your environments are set up for each platform, using the same code will be mostly trivial.

Although cocos2d-x does not support 3D animations, its [documentation](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki) may help you get started for cross-platform apps using openGL.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://impactjs.com/ for iOS they are allowing you to use threeJS //asmallgame.com/labsopen/webgl_impact/  right now for Android it is only supported on Chrome Beta and you have to enable the flag http://thenextweb.com/google/2013/01/25/google-finally-makes-it-easy-to-enable-webgl-support-in-latest-chrome-for-android-beta/ I would expect webGL to be fully supported with key lime pie version of android coming out soon.  Also you can hack the iAd platform to support it on iOS but you will not get it through the app store due to using private libraries. github.com/benvanik/WebGLBrowser  also be aware of github.com/kripken/emscripten because firefox recently came out with asmJS on odin monkey techcrunch.com/2013/03/21/firefox-nightly-now-includes-odinmonkey-brings-javascript-performance-closer-to-running-at-native-speeds/ this enabled firefox to port over unreal engine to webgl in only a few days at the last GDC so hopefully chrome and other browser start supporting asmJS for the obvious speed boost. techcrunch.com/2013/03/27/mozilla-and-epic-games-bring-unreal-engine-3-to-the-web-no-plugin-needed/